# datepicker not work in live method

Tags: jquery

my datepicker is work in simple code. after using that in insert new row of `<tr>` not work in click. but i can get object of that in first click into `<input/>`.
thats work when clicking other `input` and try again to click for showing popup of datepicker.

My jQuery:

```
$('#myTable tr:last').after("<tr><td align='center'style='background-color:"+rcolor+"'>"+rowCount+
            "</td><td><input style='width:300px !important;' name='onvan' /></td>"+
            "<td><input style='width:100px !important;' name='' id='startdate'/></td>"+
            "<td><input style='width:100px !important;' name='' id='enddate'/></td>"+
            "<td><input style='width:100px !important;' name='' id='' /></td>"+
            "<td>"+
            "<select name='visible'>"+
            "<option></option>"+
            "<option></option>"+
            "<option></option>"+
            "<option></option>"+
            "<option></option>"+
            "<option></option>"+
            "</select></td>"+
            "<td><select name='visible'><option value='1' >فعال</option><option value='0' >غیرفعال</option></select>"+
            "&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id='saveToDb'><a href='#'>ذخیره</a></span>&nbsp;<span id='cancelToSave'><a href='#'>لفو</a></span></td>"+
            "</tr>");
```

DATAPICKER:

```
$(function() {
    $('#startdate').live('click', function() {
        // alert( $(this));

             $(this).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
                minDate: '-3y',
                maxDate: '+3y',
                regional: 'fa',
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                         var date = new JalaliDate(inst['selectedYear'], inst['selectedMonth'], inst['selectedDay']).getGregorianDate();
                          var month= (date.getMonth()+1).toString(); 
                          if (month.length <2) month='0'+ month; 

                          var day= date.getDate().toString(); 
                          if (day.length <2) day ='0'+ day;
                          $('#taTarikh').val(date.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day);
                          // alert($('#taTarikh').val());
                }
             });    
          });                 
});
```

Comment: this will cause a second click to make datepicker work and i dont see anything wrong here.

Comment: Is your element with id 'startdate' unique?

Comment: @BerkerYüceer i'm waiting 3 min, but thats not work.thats show when click other `input` and back to click to `startdate` thats work

Comment: @TuxWorld here is a demonstration http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/pBQFF/ it will offcourse start at second click. try double clicking and you will see the result. if you want it to work with only one click than add the date picker after appending with its id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.live('click',function(){});` you are implementing datepicker by your first click thats why it starts working at second click.

You should implement datepicker after you create the object..

```
$(function() {
    $('#myTable tr:last').after("<tr><td align='center'style='background-color:yellow'>3</td><td><input style='width:300px !important;' name='onvan' /></td>" + "<td><input style='width:100px !important;' name='' id='startdate'/></td>" + "<td><input style='width:100px !important;' name='' id='enddate'/></td>" + "<td><input style='width:100px !important;' name='' id='' /></td>" + "<td>" + "<select name='visible'>" + "<option></option>" + "<option></option>" + "<option></option>" + "<option></option>" + "<option></option>" + "<option></option>" + "</select></td>" + "<td><select name='visible'><option value='1' >فعال</option><option value='0' >غیرفعال</option></select>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id='saveToDb'><a href='#'>ذخیره</a></span>&nbsp;<span id='cancelToSave'><a href='#'>لفو</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");
    $("#startdate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        minDate: '-3y',
        maxDate: '+3y',
        regional: 'fa',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = new JalaliDate(inst['selectedYear'], inst['selectedMonth'], inst['selectedDay']).getGregorianDate();
            var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
            if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            var day = date.getDate().toString();
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
            $('#taTarikh').val(date.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day);
            // alert($('#taTarikh').val());
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/pBQFF/14/